# AppleScript to minimize all visible windows is very slow. How to speed it up?

Tags: performance, applescript, minimize

Running OS X Lion 10.7.2 on a brand new (fall 2011) 13" MacBook Pro 2.4GHz.

I found the AppleScript below, which minimizes all visible windows, but it runs very very slow as an application.

When it is open in the AppleScript Editor and I click Run, it works fast enough meaning it starts right away, and after a few seconds all the windows are minimized. But when I save it as an application, I can start the application and it can be 5 to 10 seconds before the windows even start to be minimized.

How can I speed this script up, so it runs faster? I found the following article that talks about using the "whose" clause, but honestly have no idea how to use it in this script:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.12/12.05/ASPerformance/index.html

The original AppleScript is found here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26811/truly-minimize-all-windows

Here is the script:

```
tell application "System Events"

set theButtons to {}

repeat with theApplication in application processes

  repeat with theWindow in windows of theApplication

    repeat with theButton in buttons of theWindow

      if ((description of theButton) is "minimize button") then

        set theButtons to theButtons & {theButton}

      end if

    end repeat

  end repeat

end repeat

repeat with theButton in theButtons

  click theButton

end repeat

end tell
```

EDIT: (RESOLVED)

Thanks to Red_Menace who got me going in the right direction!

I think this will be the script I use, until I figure out how to do this in xcode:

```
tell application "System Events"
  repeat with appProc in (every application process whose visible is true)
    click (first button of every window of appProc whose role description is "minimize button")
  end repeat
end tell
```

EDIT: Running as Application

Not sure why, but when you save an AppleScript as an application it takes 5 to 10 seconds before it even starts, as compared to keeping it as a script. The problem with keeping it as a script is that you cannot create an alias to the script file because it will open the script file up in the editor instead of running it. The solution: Start up Automator and choose New Application. Then look for Action called Run AppleScript, and drag it over to the right hand side. Copy and Paste your AppleScript into this box, and save it and you now have an application that runs as fast as the applescript did, and you can create an alias on your desktop.

EDIT: March 2015: Found a better solution for this: Better Touch Tool (it's free) has a "Hide All Windows" shortcut that works like Windows, where it actually minimizes and hides all open windows (unlike OSX default of just moving them off the screen). You can assign it to any keyboard combo or mouse movement... I have assigned it to "OPTION_KEY + Move_Mouse_Into_Lower_Left_Corner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted script doesn't really work that well, since it gets *every* process (this can be fixed by just getting the visible application processes) and the items for the repeat loops are dynamic, which can result in windows that are not minimized (this can be fixed by explicitly getting the UI items).  With that said, I think the majority of the delay is when the application first starts up, so you might try running your script from the **Scripts Menu** instead.

As for the whose clause, it could go something like:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theResults to get buttons of (windows of (application processes whose visible is true)) whose description is "minimize button" -- a list of visible applications, containing a list of windows, containing a list of (one) buttons

    repeat with anApp in theResults
        if contents of anApp is not in {} then -- windows are open
            repeat with eachWindow in (items of anApp)
                click first item of eachWindow -- only the one minimize button
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I do however get the following error when I run it: `Can’t get item 1 of {}`. To get around this, i wrapped the `click first item of eachWindow` with `if contents of eachWindow is not {} then` and an `end if`. And also, if I display the contents of theResults, I notice that ALWAYS has the same list of windows in it, whether they are already minimized or not, so I think visible property is true even for a minimized window, but (I think) it would only be false for windows that are hidden.

Comment: This script solves the bugs I was seeing before where some, but not all the windows would get minimized, so now they ALL get minimized (thanks for a good side effect). It is faster than my original script, since it does not repeat thru background processes as well. If I save it as an application though, it is still taking 5 to 15 seconds before it even starts running. If I run it from the Scripts Menu, then it runs just as fast as when I click play in the AppleScript Editor.

Comment: Just some more questions, out of curiosity ... #1 Can you create an Alias to a script in the Scripts Menu and have it Run the script instead of opening it up in AppleScript Editor? #2 Can the two repeat loops somehow be combined into one line with a whose clause something like `click first item of eachWindow whose (some combination the two repeat loops)` #3 Can an AppleScript be imported in either Automator or Xcode and be converted to an application that will run faster than an application created by AppleScript?

Comment: I tried this and it does not cause any errors but is also does not do anything! `click (first button of (every window of (every application process whose visible is true)) whose role description is "minimize button")`

Comment: The error mentioned in your first comment is probably due to a window that doesn't have a minimize button (didn't check for that).  Aliases placed in the Scripts Menu will run without opening the script in the editor, and I would guess that an Xcode application may be faster.  The whose clause only works for application items, and since it returns a list of matching items (even if there are none), you will need to loop through at least some of the results (for example to weed out empty lists items) when using multiple filters.

Comment: Thanks ... this was very helpful. I posted a better script up in the top and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a script on: http://murphymac.com/hide-everything/ which works like a charm on macos Sierra

```
tell application "Finder"
set visible of every process whose visible is true and name is not "Finder" to false
close every window 
end tell
```